# insert into table from another table if there is any duplicates do not insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Ok I have a database with a table LOOKUP (1st), and the same database on another server also with LOOKUP (2nd).

Is there a way I can insert into the 1st database from the second, if duplicate exist then skip else all other values that is present in 2nd should be inserted into 1st. Basically I want the exact same Database!

The think that confuses me is they are on different servers.

Can I export the one to like excel and import it again and replace my database or anything.

Comment: You might want to look into the MERGE statement

Comment: Ok ive look at it ans look like what I want, now what about the databases on defferent servers

Comment: first verify wether you can access 2nd database from 1st database server.use server1
select * from [server].[database2].[dbo].lookup
if this is scuccessful then use merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use 2 `MERGE` queries if you want to make both the databases identical. This is because the first merge will only insert records that are available in DB1 into DB2. But, DB1 will still not contain the records present in DB2 but not in DB1.

I would suggest you to do this task using `SSIS`.

You can use 2 sources DB1 and DB2 and a `LOOKUP` transformation on each source (LKP1 and LKP2).
Then you can insert the No Match output of LKP1 into DB2 as destination and No Match output of LKP2 into DB1 as destination.

This will solve the multi-server issue as well because you can create connection to any server in SSIS.